Computing an iterated integral by iteratively applying the 1D trapezoidal rule
I have a Python function, called trap_1D, which computes the (approximate) integral of a univariate function f over an interval [a,b] using the composite trapezoidal rule. Now I want to evaluate an iterated integral of the form \int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} f(x,y) dy dx by iteratively calling trap_1D: Below is trap_1D:
import numpy as np

def trap_1D(func, a, b, N, *args):
    
    #Computes the integral of a univariate function over [a, b] using the composite trapezoidal rule.

    h = (b - a) / N                #The grid spacing
    x = np.linspace(a, b, N + 1)   #The sub-division points: x_0, x_1,...,x_N.
    y = func(x, *args)            
    
    return (np.sum(y) - (y[0] + y[-1]) / 2) * h

I've tested trap_1D on a few functions and it works. Next, I constructed a function I(x) := \int_{a}^{b} f(x,y) dy.
def create_I(f, a, b, N):
    def I(x):
        return trap_1D(lambda y: f(x, y), a, b, N)  #integrate the function y --> f(x,y) 
    
    return I

I've tested create_I and it works. Now to test out evaluating iterated integrals I'm using f(x,y) = sin(x) * sin(y) as my test function, which I want to integrate over the rectangle [0,pi/2] x [0,pi/2]:
def f(x,y): 
    return np.sin(x)*np.cos(y)

N = 100
I = create_I(f, 0.0, np.pi/2, N)   #The function I() is correct
I2 = trap_1D(I, 0.0, np.pi/2, N)   #This gives an error 

The last line gives the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15880\410820249.py in <module>
     26 N = 100
     27 I = create_I(f, 0.0, np.pi/2, 100)
---> 28 trap_1D(I, 0.0, np.pi/2, N)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15880\410820249.py in trap_1D(func, a, b, N, *args)
      9     y = func(x, *args)
     10 
---> 11     return (np.sum(y) - (y[0] + y[-1]) / 2) * h
     12 
     13 

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

I don't understand this error. What is causing the problem here?

Your create_I function should return a vectorized version of I. Currently, when the linspace x is passed into the function, I spits out a scalar, when you want it to spit out a vector. This should be solved by changing the return statement in create_I:
def create_I(f, a, b, N):
    def I(x):
        return trap_1D(lambda y: f(x, y), a, b, N)
    
    return np.vectorize(I)


The error tells you what's happening. You're trying to use index access on a scalar variable, in this case one instance of y.
As to why: trap_1D returns a floating point number (a scalar), which is also the return type of I. When your f is passed as func to trap_1D, there's no problem since y (the variable inside trap_1D) has the same shape as x since it's the return value of f. However, when I is passed as func to trap_1D, then this variable is suddenly the return value of I, i.e. trap_1D(f,...), and your trap_1D always returns a scalar float. You try to access elements of this float by index in y[0], y[-1], but float is a scalar, it doesn't support that operation.
